# logstash elastic search output configuration based on inputs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

Is there any way I can use logstash configuration file to scale output accordingly with different types/indexes ?

For eg.,

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "index_resources"
    if(%{some_field_id}==kb){
         document_type => "document_type"
         document_id => "%{some_id}"
    }
   else {
        document_type => "other_document_type"
        document_id => "%{some_other_id}"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could route your documents to multiple indexes within your `logstash` itself. `Output` could look something like this:

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
    if %{some_field_id} == "kb" {  <---- insert your condition here
        elasticsearch {  
            host => "localhost"  
            protocol => "http"  
            index => "index1"
            document_type => "document_type"
            document_id => "%{some_id}"   
        }
    } else {
        elasticsearch {  
            host => "localhost"  
            protocol => "http"  
            index => "index2"
            document_type => "other_document_type"
            document_id => "%{some_other_id}"   
        }
    }
}
```

This [thread](https://gist.github.com/jhmartin/c09e450853e273ee88f2) might help you as well.